# How can you capitalize this word in VIM snippet?

Tags: javascript, vim, code-snippets, vscode-snippets, ultisnips

EDIT — This is [not possible](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-snippets/issues/62) with coc-snippets. It's possible with Ultisnips.

I've got the following vim snippet that I'm using (with coc-snippets) for React:

```
snippet STATE_HOOK "useState hook" b
const [${1:state}, set${1:`!v expand('%:t:r')`}] = useState($2)
endsnippet
```

This could be used to quickly create the following (incorrect) code:

```
const [color, setcolor] = useState("green");
```

The problem is that the `setcolor` needs to be camelcased, like this: `setColor`

How would one write this snippet so that the expanded input is capitalized?

Comment: This is now possible with regular vscode snippets.  Support has been added for case modifiers like `\u`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was testing some different things and you can use:

```
snippet STATE_HOOK "useState hook" b
const [$1, set${1/\w+/\u$0/g}] = useState("$2")
endsnippet
```

How it works:
Checking the [documentation](https://www.sirver.net/blog/2012/01/08/second-episode-of-ultisnips-screencast/) I found that you should overrite the text with the same text but capitalized, so `\w+`takes all the text (I think that '+' is unnecesary) and overrite it with `\u$0` (is the same text but capitalized)

[image]

Comment: This is great. The reason that I'd been running into problems on my own (and this answer pointed me in the right direction) was because I'd been trying to use coc-snippets, which doesn't support capitalization.

Comment: doesn't work on my end, using coc-snippets

Comment: Hey, yeah its because coc-snippets doesn't support the \u modifier (uppercase modifier). I'd recommend just installing Utilsnips instead, ended up going that route and it works. See here: https://github.com/neoclide/coc-snippets/issues/62

Answer (score -1):

Strings like `foo-bar` or `foo_bar` are easy to turn into `fooBar` and `fooBar` is easy to turn into `foo-bar` or `foo_bar` because the two parts are easily identifiable, which gives you a structure to work with.

There is no such thing with `usecolor`. There is no separator and everything is of the same case so you can get quite a bunch of valid camel-cased names out of that string: `usecOlor`, `uSeCoLor`, etc.

You have three options:

1. camel-case your filenames so that you don't have to perform any transformation,
2. kebab-case or snake-case your filenames to make them easy to transform with a simple substitution,
3. come up with extensive rules and find out how to transform random strings in a satisfactory and reproducible way.

I would go with number 1.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however the caveat here is that I'm only looking to capitalize the word after "set." The "set" string will always be "set" and never anything else. That's the reason I'm thinking this is definitely possible... Meaning, if the pattern is always set{variable} it should be possible to capitalize the variable string.